# docker-compose.yml vs docker-stack.yml what difference?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new docker-user. And in difference manuals I have find usually docker-compose.yml file for description docker job, but on docker site for this goal used docker-stack.yml file. What difference?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

docker-compose.yml is for the docker-compose tool which is for multi container docker applications on a single docker engine.

its called with

```
docker-compose up
```

docker-stack.yml is for the docker swarm tool. (for orchestration and scheduling).

its called with

```
docker stack
```

Comment: Okay, for what (practical)goal better use docker swarm tool, and can i compare them?

Comment: The official docker introduction uses docker-compose.yml with `docker stack` so I guess it's just a naming convention.

Comment: @meowsqueak the offical docker-compose docs uses docker-compose. as you can see here https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/ the 3 point on the top of the sheet. 1. make Dockerfile, 2. make docker-compose.yml, 3. docker-compose up

Comment: @Gabbax0r sure, that's the docker-compose docs though, not the docker docs. I was referring to the Get Started "introduction" for *Docker* which makes use of docker-compose.yml with `docker stack` but never mentions the `docker-compose` tool itself. A minor documentation inconsistency perhaps. https://docs.docker.com/get-started/

Answer (score 8):

To add to Gabbax0r reply:

Docker Swarm was a standalone component used to cluster Docker engines as a single one.

As of Docker 1.12 the "Swarm" standalone was integrated inside the Docker engine ([read the preamble at this page](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/discovery/)), and Swarm is (or will be) legacy.

To reply to your original question, it is just different names for different cases, but they both are meant to serve the same purpose.

To reply to your comment question, use docker-compose when you have to orchestrate a multi-container app on a single node; if you have to worry about multi-nodes and load-balancing and all this advanced stuff, you better off go with the Swarm.

Comment: Why not use Swarm on a single node too

Comment: @KajMagnus You could, but what is that you are trying to achieve then?

Comment: Linuxbnndit: then, when you learn Swarm for a single node, you'll learn Swarm syntax and terminology, rather than Docker-Compose. Later, if you want to scale to many nodes, you'll be familiar with Swarm already, and all tools you might have built, will use Swarm commands already. So you'd save some time. ... I actually posted a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45993496/any-reasons-to-not-use-docker-swarm-instead-of-docker-compose-on-a-single-nodev

Answer (score 0):

The **docker-stack.yml** has the advantage over **docker-compose.yml** :

1. Update separately

   > When working with services, swarms, and docker-stack.yml files, keep in mind that the tasks (containers) backing a service **[can be deployed on any node](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes-for-services-swarms-and-stack-files#volumes-for-services-swarms-and-stack-files)** in a swarm.

   This may be applied to a different node each time the service is updated.
2. Deploy remotely

   > If you are running **[Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/)** on your private host then docker-stack.yml can use to access and deploy your application remotely to the host using an SSH key.

   You may even use such a service like [*Codefresh*](https://codefresh.io/docs/docs/deploy-your-containers/docker-swarm/)  to do so.