# Any reasons to not use Docker Swarm (instead of Docker-Compose) on a single node?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

There's Docker Swarm (now built into Docker) and Docker-Compose. People seem to use Docker-Compose when running containers on a single node only. However, Docker-Compose doesn't support any of the `deploy` config values, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#deploy, which include `mem_limit` and `cpus`, which seems like nice/important to be able to set.

So therefore maybe I should use Docker Swarm? although I'm deploying on a single node only. Also, then the installation instructions will be simpler for other people to follow (they won't need to install Docker-Compose).

But maybe there are reasons why I should not use Swarm on a single node?

I'm posting an answer below, but I'm not sure if it's correct.

<sub>*Edit:* Please note that this is not an opinion based question. If you have a look at the answer below, you'll see that there are *"have-to"* and *"cannot-do"* facts about this.</sub>

Answer (score 9):

For development, use Docker-Compose. Because only Docker-Compose is able to read your Dockerfiles and build images for you. Docker Stack instead needs pre-built *images*. Also, with Docker-Compose, you can easily start and stop single containers, with `docker-compose kill ...` and `... start ...`. This is useful, during development (in my experience). For example, to see how the app server reacts if you kill the database. Then you don't want Swarm to auto-restart the database directly.

In production, use Docker Swarm (unless: see below), so you can configure mem limits. Docker-Compose has less functionality that Docker Swarm (no mem or cpu limits for example) and doesn't have anything that Swarm does *not* have (right?). So no reason to use Compose in production. (Except maybe if you know how Compose works already and don't want to spend time reading about the new Swarm commands.)

Docker Swarm doesn't, however, support `.env` files like Docker-Compose does. So you cannot have e.g. `IMAGE_VERSION=1.2.3` in an `.env` file and then in the `docker-compose.yml` file have: `image: name:${IMAGE_VERSION}`. See https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29133 — instead you'll need to set env vars "manually": `IMAGE_VERSION=SOMETHING docker stack up ...` (this actually made me stick with Docker-Compose. + that I didn't reasonably quickly find out how to view a container's log, via Swarm; Swarm seemed more complicated.)

Comment: You right about `.env` file but this issue usually can be fixed by this way: `env $(cat .env | grep ^[A-Z] | xargs) docker stack deploy ...`

Comment: Another important reason to use Docker Swarm in production is proper secrets support. You can use file-based secrets with compose, which just get bind-mounted in this case, but that is not secure!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @KajMagnus answer I should note that Docker Swarm still don't support Linux Capabilities as Docker [Compose] do. You can learn about this issue and dive into Docker community discussions [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/824516/how-to-set-linux-capabilities-on-docker-swarm-mode-service-invocations).

Comment: Docker Swarm now supports capabilities as of version 20.10.0, See https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/2663